# UIView with shadow, rounded only top corners and masked bottom edge

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, shadow, rounded-corners

I'm struggling to achieve the view that would have rounded only top corners and shadow around it. The whole view should be masked at the bottom by the superview to prevent the shadow to overlap following subview (shadow offset should be (0, 0)).

When I use:

```
    // Adding shadow
    let contentSubviewLayer = contentSubview.layer
    contentSubviewLayer.masksToBounds = false
    contentSubviewLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    contentSubviewLayer.shadowRadius = 2.5
    contentSubviewLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
    contentSubviewLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    contentSubviewLayer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: contentSubview.bounds).CGPath
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

I get:
[image]

But after adding masking the bottom edge:

```
    // Adding maskView to round only top corners
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.contentSubview.bounds
    let roundedPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: maskLayer.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.TopLeft, UIRectCorner.TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(CORNER_RADIUS, CORNER_RADIUS))
    maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    maskLayer.path = roundedPath.CGPath
    contentSubview.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

I'm getting:
[image]

The desired effect should be the conjunction of the two above and should resemble something like this with **shadows around the left, top and right edges**:
[image]

Please help!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you just put another view of the same background color on top of your bottom part to cover the undesired part?

Comment: No, because it will be a table view section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use an app called PaintCode to generate the Swift code I need for this type of thing. I did something similar recently and it spat this out for me:

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //// Color Declarations
    let chiesi_light_grey = UIColor(red: 0.851, green: 0.851, blue: 0.851, alpha: 1.000)

    //// Shadow Declarations
    let chiesi_shadow = NSShadow()
    chiesi_shadow.shadowColor = chiesi_light_grey.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8 * CGColorGetAlpha(chiesi_light_grey.CGColor))
    chiesi_shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.1, height: 4.1)
    chiesi_shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 54), byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.BottomLeft, UIRectCorner.BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))
    rectanglePath.closePath()
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, chiesi_shadow.shadowOffset, chiesi_shadow.shadowBlurRadius, (chiesi_shadow.shadowColor as! UIColor).CGColor)
    UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
    rectanglePath.fill()
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)

    chiesi_light_grey.setStroke()
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 2
    rectanglePath.stroke()
```

Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Hi,great answer, thank you very much! This solved my problem. Of course I had to set `shadowOffset` to `(0, 0)`, adjust shadow color, change rounded corners to `[TopLeft, TopRight]` and remove the 3 bottom lines of the code responsible for stroking the lines.